# PyQt5 QHeaderView::up-arrow styles not working

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

Python 3, Most recent version of PyQt5 (C++ Answers are acceptable)
Using a generic QTableWidget

I'm using a dark themed GUI with a QTableWidget and have been trying to change the appearance of the sort arrows on the headers since they are a dark color. I can't seem to get them to work properly. Changing the font color for QHeaderView::up-arrow doesn't affect anything. Changing the background color converts it to a small rectangle of the specified color with no arrows.

Qt has an example on how to style the QHeaderView arrows here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview

When I replace the image like the example shows, it appears really, really small. Adding a height and width does nothing.

Also, I've tried moving the arrow to other places using "subcontrol-position: center right;" as I've witnessed in other examples to no effect. All I really want to do is make the arrow white and possibly slightly larger than the default for visibility. I can use an image if needed. It would be nice to have the option to move the arrow as well but I can live without that.

If your solution involves subclassing the QHeaderView and overwriting the paint event or dealing with Proxies, please give examples of what to do as I'm not very familiar with those topics.

Edit: 
Generic dark themed QTableWidget using Qt Designer with image.
Converted to python using pyuic5.

main.py (Run this file)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("*{\n"
"background-color: #333;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QHeaderView:section{\n"
"background-color: rgba(255,255,255,50);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QHeaderView:up-arrow{\n"
"image: url(:/arrow/up_arrow.png);\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, item)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "bob"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "fred"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "george"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)

import Resources_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Qt Resource file containing up_arrow.png image converted to python using pyrcc5. Put in same directory as main.py.

Must Name the following as "Resources_rc.py":

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Resource object code
#
# Created by: The Resource Compiler for PyQt5 (Qt v5.6.2)
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore

qt_resource_data = b"\
\x00\x00\x00\x81\
\x89\
\x50\x4e\x47\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x0d\x49\x48\x44\x52\x00\
\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x04\x00\x00\x00\x4a\x7e\xf5\x73\
\x00\x00\x00\x48\x49\x44\x41\x54\x38\xcb\x63\x60\x18\x05\x83\x18\
\xfc\x6f\xf8\xdf\x40\x9a\x72\x10\x68\x20\x45\xf9\x1f\x20\x24\x4e\
\x0b\x58\xf9\xef\xff\x61\xff\xc3\x89\xd2\x02\x53\x0e\x66\x13\xd6\
\x02\x55\x1e\x0a\xe7\x13\xd2\x02\xd4\xf0\xfb\x7f\x08\x8a\x08\x48\
\x4b\x1d\x3e\x3b\xb4\x08\x8b\x8c\x82\xc1\x00\x00\xa1\x30\x49\xa2\
\x19\xa1\xab\xc2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x49\x45\x4e\x44\xae\x42\x60\x82\
\
"

qt_resource_name = b"\
\x00\x05\
\x00\x68\x99\x67\
\x00\x61\
\x00\x72\x00\x72\x00\x6f\x00\x77\
\x00\x0c\
\x06\xe6\xe6\x67\
\x00\x75\
\x00\x70\x00\x5f\x00\x61\x00\x72\x00\x72\x00\x6f\x00\x77\x00\x2e\x00\x70\x00\x6e\x00\x67\
"

qt_resource_struct = b"\
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\
\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\
"

def qInitResources():
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

def qCleanupResources():
    QtCore.qUnregisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

qInitResources()
```

I have also tried making the qss for the QHeaderView read as follows to move the arrow from above the text to the right of the text to no avail:

```
QHeaderView:up-arrow {
subcontrol-position: center right;
}
```

Comment: could provide a [mcve] and show what you have tried.